# Laravel 5.0 eager loading breaks relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this repository (PaymentRepository) the partial of what I'm stack at is this:

```
$location_id = \Request::get('location');
$transactions = Payment::where($paymentCondition)->with(array(
    'client' => function($query) use ($location_id) {
        if($location_id) $query->where('location_id', $location_id);
    }))->paginate(50);
```

When there isn't a location picked the payment does have a relation available with client, this is what I see when dumping a record

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "client" => Client {#578 ▶}
]
```

After a location is picked, relation is immediately broken then dumping record shows this

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "client" => null
]
```

Though when I perform toSql to query and dump it, the result is this:

```
"select * from `payments`"
```

Does eager loading (`with(array('client'=>`) break a relationship?,
currently Payment class has this connection with Client class:

```
public function client() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'client_id' ,'id');
}
```

Comment: When you don't choose a location / region, what is the output of `location_id`? Also, try returning the query in the closure (`return $query`);

Comment: Hey there Mr. Bauman, when there is no location picked its null otherwise its the id of location, I checked it within the closure. In both cases the query returns collection of payments just the differenc is with eager loading, it just doesn't load the relation of client, which seems to be kinda weird..

Comment: That's strange... Try dumping the the nested query and see what bindings are there? (`dd($query)`)

Comment: Hey there Mr. Bauman, I've moved to a raw query for now as here is an emergency case, will try to switch back to eloquent query if a solution pops out. In some spare time I'll try to dump everything furthermore. Thanks a lot for your attention.